# Where can I view the history of the questions I asked Gemini when asked through Gmail/Drive?

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google

Google Gemini can be used in Gmail, Drive, Docs, Slides, Sheets and Meet. E.g., in GDrive:

[image]

Where can I view the history of the questions I asked Gemini when asked through Gmail/Drive?

I don't see it on  https://gemini.google.com/ and https://myactivity.google.com/product/bard (still called Bard there), but maybe I missed it